# how to select nodes from a gv file with DiagrammR in R

Tags: r, graphviz, diagrammer

I have a `test.gv` file with nodes and edges like

```
digraph a_nice_graph {
  
  # node definitions with substituted label text
  node [fontname = Helvetica]
  a [label = '@@1'parti = acteur]
  b [label = '@@2-1' parti = acteur]
  c [label = '@@2-2' parti = acteur]
  d [label = '@@2-3' parti = resource]
  e [label = '@@2-4' parti = resource]
  f [label = '@@2-5' parti = resource]
  g [label = '@@2-6' parti = resource]
  h [label = '@@2-7' parti = resource]
  i [label = '@@2-8' parti = resource]
  j [label = '@@2-9' parti = resource]
  
  # edge definitions with the node IDs
  a -> {d e f g h i j}
  b -> {a d e f g h i j}
  c -> {d e f g h i j}
}
```

readable with `DiagrammeR::grViz("/tmp/test.gv")`

[image: exemple graph]

I would like to manipulate the objects (node and edges) with the functions of the DiagrammR package to make subgraphs according to the attributes.
I don't understand how to put my objects in a variable and then manipulate them.

Comment: Can we select nodes in diagrammer::grviz graphs inside R? I have never heard about it...

Comment: I don't know but in the package I have a [select_nodes](https://rich-iannone.github.io/DiagrammeR/selections.html) function. So I expected it to be possible.

Comment: yes, but it works for not grviz graphs. https://rdrr.io/cran/DiagrammeR/man/select_nodes.html